# how to get SUPER priviledge to create a trigger in mariadb

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to create a trigger and whenever i do i get the following error:

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

This is the code that i used:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS change_interest_rate $$
CREATE TRIGGER change_interest_rate
  BEFORE UPDATE ON CHINA
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @old_interest = OLD.EXCHANGE_RATE;
  SET @new_interest = NEW.EXCHANGE_RATE;
  CALL change_interest_rate('CNY', @old_interest, @new_interest);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Been on this one for a while now and can't figure out how to get around this. I tried using:

```
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

But then I got an error saying:

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Even though I have been granted all permissions on my database. Can someone kindly help?

Thanks!

Comment: 'ALL' <> 'SUPER'

Comment: Will the two `SETs` and the `CALL` work if executed outside the Trigger?  What does `change_interest_rate` do?  If it is just an `INSERT` then you do _not_ want to replicate the trigger.